# How to edit individual cells in a Data Grid in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a `DataGrid` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`, and implemented using an MVVM structure. My question is how do I edit individual cells in a `DataGrid` implemented like this in C#?

**Data Model:**

This is the implementation of the `ObservableCollection` bound to the `DataGrid`.

```
private ObservableCollection<IoData> _ioCollection;

public Data_Model()
{
    IOCollection = new ObservableCollection<IoData>();
    IOCollection.Add(new IoData() { rowNum = 0, input = _input0, output = _output0});
    IOCollection.Add(new IoData() { rowNum = 1, input = _input1, output = _output1});
    IOCollection.Add(new IoData() { rowNum = 2, input = _input2, output = _output2});
}

//**Update 1: showing my Collection's property**

public ObservableCollection<IoData> IOCollection
{
    get { return _ioCollection; }
    set
    {
        _ioCollection = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => IOCollection);
    }
}
```

**xaml:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data_Model.IOCollection}" ... />
```

I would be doing this from a `Command` in my ViewModel. Would I just replace the row that contains the cell and add in the data that is being changed? I'm really just unsure how to work with a `DataGrid` that is created with an `ObservableCollection`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you edit the items in your observable collection, aren't you in a sense, `editing individual cells`?

Comment: You don't "edit the UI" in WPF. if you want to modify your data, then modify your data.

Comment: @HighCore I know that. I am just unsure how to modify the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit the item in your ObservableCollection and it will update the `cell` accordingly.

Your class `IoData` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so your properties will update on the UI(View) when changes are made.

Comment: I think this is something that I already knew, so sorry if I came off differently. I guess I just need to know how I would edit `_input1` for example (I am unsure how to target and change that item in the collection).

Comment: Assuming you want to get a specific one that matches some criteria? Use LINQ: 

var ioItem = IOCollection.FirstOrDefault(io => io.rowNum == 1);
ioItem.input = "new input";

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data object (IoData in your example) implements INotifyPropertyChanged correctly, you would just need a reference to the data object of interest and update the property. The change would automatically propagate to your DataGrid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: To edit the data, you could access it as data[1].input. The index you use could easily be attached to the SelectedIndex property of the DataGrid or something similar. If something else holds a reference to the same IOData object (if it was constructed somewhere other than the "Add" statement) any changes to that reference would also update the DataGrid.